# Bitmap size exceeds 32bits - for restore state view from cache

Tags: android, bitmap, android-4.4-kitkat

For KitKat, when system restore previous state for my activity, application throws an exception - `bitmap size exceeds 32bits`

My activity contain `ScrollView` with `WebView` with large content, large tiles image on background and other.

when view restore state in code

package android.view;

**View.java**

```
12848            final long projectedBitmapSize = width * height * (opaque && !use32BitCache ? 2 : 4);
12849            final long drawingCacheSize =
12850                    ViewConfiguration.get(mContext).getScaledMaximumDrawingCacheSize();
12851            if (width <= 0 || height <= 0 || projectedBitmapSize > drawingCacheSize) {
12852                if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
12853                    Log.w(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs "
12854                            + projectedBitmapSize + " bytes, only "
12855                            + drawingCacheSize + " available");
12856                }
12857                destroyDrawingCache();
12858                mCachingFailed = true;
12859                return;
12860            }
```

We get negative value in:

```
final long projectedBitmapSize = width * height * (opaque && !use32BitCache ? 2 : 4);
```

For example:

```
autoScale = true
attachInfo = {android.view.View$AttachInfo@830038767120}
height = 1174671
width = 768
drawingCacheBackgroundColor = 0
scalingRequired = false
opaque = false
use32BitCache = true
drawingCacheSize = 4096000
projectedBitmapSize = -686377984
clear = true
mUnscaledDrawingCache = null
mDrawingCache = null
```

How to fix it?